# Pandemic, Global Epidemic, Epidemic, Endemic

Tags: differences

I really want to hear from the experts the definitions of all 4 terms especially whether global epidemic is equivalent to pandemic. Or should this question be directed to the epidemiologist?

1. Pandemic
2. Global Epidemic
3. Epidemic
4. Endemic

I have Googled the terms and I understand the definition of 1), 3) and 4). In short the definition is based on geographical location and scale of outbreak, Pandemic is an outbreak of disease on a global scale (e.g. HIV). Epidemic is an outbreak of disease on a localised area. Endemic is a disease in a localised area. However, a definition for Global Epidemic is not available online.

Recently, WHO mentioned that "“It is important to put this on the table: this virus(Covid19) may become just another **endemic virus** in our communities, and this virus may never go away,” WHO emergencies expert Mike Ryan told an online briefing." Isn't covid19 considered a pandemic since it is on a global scale and is spreading rapidly?

Another term that I come across often is **Global Epidemic**. For example in the WHO website, HIV is listed as **Global Epidemic**. Does that mean Pandemic and Global Epidemic are the same?

Comment: "endemic" is an adjective, not a noun. There's no such thing as "global endemic".

Comment: A pandemic has a technical definition given by the medical community. The authoritative experts are more likely to be found there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global epidemic is a pandemic. According to the Mayo Clinic:

> A pandemic refers to a global epidemic — one that has spread over several countries or continents affecting a large number of people. Dr. Pritish Tosh adds, "In epidemiologic terms, an outbreak refers to a number of cases that exceeds what would be expected. A pandemic is when there is an outbreak that affects most of the world. We use the term endemic when there is an infection within a geographic location that is existing perpetually."

The WHO “declares” a pandemic, which may have certain consequences in the actions taken by member states. Whether WHO declares it or not a disease may be a pandemic.

The set of words may be used metaphorically to describe problems such as child abuse or spousal abuse that are widespread but not contagious as are dIseases arising from viruses, bacteria, and fungi.

Answer (score 1):

"endemic" is an adjective that means that the condition is found commonly in an area or community. It's not specific to the size of the community. It's possible for something to be endemic in the whole world.

So if COVID-19 doesn't go away, it will become endemic in all the communities that have not eradicated it, just as the common cold is.

As for your other terms, the distinction between epidemic and pandemic is fuzzy and there's some overlap. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/epidemic-vs-pandemic-difference) describes it this way:

> An epidemic is defined as “an outbreak of disease that spreads quickly and affects many individuals at the same time.” A pandemic is a type of epidemic (one with greater range and coverage), an outbreak of a disease that occurs over a wide geographic area and affects an exceptionally high proportion of the population. While a pandemic may be characterized as a type of epidemic, you would not say that an epidemic is a type of pandemic.

Comment: Does changing pandemic to global endemic entail sort of situation is under control but widespread?

Comment: No. Endemic just means common.

Comment: For instance, HIV is endemic in the gay community, poverty and malnutrition are endemic in third world countries.

Comment: So HIV is endemic, pandemic and global epidemic?

Comment: From Wikipedia: HIV/AIDS, or Human Immunodeficiency Virus, is considered by some authors a global pandemic. However, the WHO currently uses the term 'global epidemic' to describe HIV.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it endemic, except among certain communities: gay men, IV drug users, and portions of Africa.