# Is it redundant to say "global pandemic"?

Tags: science, redundancy

It seems that the word *pandemic* is generally understood to refer to a large or global geographic area.  Is it therefore redundant to say "global pandemic" in a sentence such as, "The restaurant is closed due to the global pandemic," or is "pandemic" by itself more stylistically correct?

Note that my question is specifically about "pandemic" versus "global pandemic," not "epidemic" as in the question [Pandemic, Global Epidemic, Epidemic, Endemic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/534486/pandemic-global-epidemic-epidemic-endemic).

Merriam Webster Unabridged<sup>[1]</sup> says for pandemic (adj):

> pan·dem·ic (*adjective*): occurring over a wide geographic area and affecting an exceptionally high proportion of the population.

Wiktionary<sup>[2]</sup> says:

> (epidemiology) Of a disease: epidemic over a wide geographical area and affecting a large proportion of the population; also, of or pertaining to a disease of this nature.

The [WHO Director-General said](https://www.who.int/dg/speeches/detail/who-director-general-s-opening-remarks-at-the-media-briefing-on-covid-19---11-march-2020) on March 11:

> There are now more than 118,000 cases in 114 countries, and 4,291 people have lost their lives.  … We have therefore made the assessment that COVID-19 can be characterized as a pandemic.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged, s.v. “pandemic,” accessed June 15, 2020, http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com.

<sup>[2]</sup> Wiktionary contributors, "pandemic," Wiktionary, The Free Dictionary, https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=pandemic&oldid=59469551 (accessed June 15, 2020).

Comment: @JasonBassford No, because "global pandemic" is not addressed in that question, only "global epidemic."

Comment: Hmm, this question seems to elicit opinions. The second part of [pandemic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pandemic) refers to people. The first part can also be found in [Pan-American](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-American). So strictly speaking it's not redundant.

Comment: I recall a TV news channel announcing that Covid 19 had broken out on the Continent of America and could therefore be termed a "pandemic", i.e. 'on all continents' (I assume nobody counts Antarctica). This is simply wrong and an invention. The adjectives (and nouns) used are **sporadic, epidemic, endemic**, and **pandemic**: in context, these terms are somewhat loose but are in order of occurrence and area, distribution within the area, and group. Despite the suffix *demic*, the words are used of animals and plants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one U.S. expert on infectious diseases noted:

> “Pandemics mean different things to different people,” National Institute of Allergy and Infectious Diseases Director Dr. Anthony Fauci said in February. “It really is borderline semantics, to be honest with you.”

The declaration of a pandemic by the World Health Organization, which it did for Coved-19 on March 11, 2020, may have significance in itself in alerting governments to the situation and requiring or recommending a variety of actions (e.g., to protect health workers) by health authorities. It may also justify actions such as closing down airpots. To this extent, it’s a pandemic if WHO declares it to be one.

https://time.com/5791661/who-coronavirus-pandemic-declaration/

Is a pandemic necessarily global? Apparently not; it can be more or less global.
Shades of grey. It could miss some significant places, and so be partly global, totally global, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't redundant at all. As you have pointed out in your research, the definition of a pandemic does not explicitly include the entire world.

Oxford:

> (of a disease) prevalent over a whole country or the world.

Wikipedia:

> A pandemic is an epidemic of an infectious disease that has spread across a large region, for instance multiple continents or worldwide.

The prefix *-pan* means *all* or *everything*, and these words can be subjective, just as "everyone" could refer to everyone in a country, everyone in a town, or everyone in the world.